# Using char *s and strcmp function in c++

Tags: c++

I have two char* references and I am trying to figure out which one is less. The code I have is:

```
bool stringComparison::lessThan(char *s1, char* s2) {
  int result = strcmp(*s1,*s2);
  return result < 0;
};
```

the result is not producing less than 0 ever. How do I need to change the "int result" line to make this work?

thanks

Comment: "I have two char* references" - no you don't, you have two values of type `char*`, that is to pointer-to-char. There are no C++ "references" in sight. Let's hope that `s1` and `s2` each point to the first character of a nul-terminated C-style string, because that's what `strcmp` requires.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

strcmp is used to compare strings; *s1 and *s2 are characters.  You should be calling strcmp with s1 and s2 (no stars).

**EDIT:**

Here is the reference for [strcmp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp)

Comment: if i only have reference to *s1 and *s2 is there a way to get the string from that?

Comment: @user1434066: You don't have *references*, you have pointers. `s1` presumably points to the first character of a string (a sequence of characters terminated by a null character `'\0'`). Given such a pointer, `strcmp` can access the entire string by indexing or by advancing a pointer to point to successive characters. Check out the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/) (I know you're doing C++, but you're using features that C++ inherited from C).

Answer (score 0):

`s1` and `s2` are strings. So your code

```
int result = strcmp(*s1,*s2);
```

should read

```
int result = strcmp(s1,s2);
```

See the on-line reference for `strcmp`.

Comment: @KeithThompson - `s1` is a `char *` - a pointer to the first character of a string. If it was `char **` then it would be a pointer to a string. Ditto for `s2`

Comment: The [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 7.1.1 paragraph 1, defines the term: "A *pointer to a string* is a pointer to its initial (lowest addressed) character."  A `char**` is a pointer to a pointer, *not* a pointer to a string.

Comment: @KeithThompson - Just going by the usage as given on the manual page for `strcmp` (http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp), also here http://cprogramminglanguage.net/c-string.aspx

Comment: That man page is incorrect, or at least uses sloppy wording. The definitions in the language standard are definitive. I've actually contacted the maintainers of the `man-pages` project about fixing this, but they haven't replied.

Answer (score 0):

You have more problems, or different problems, than what you've told us.

In the code you've shown us, the `s1` and `s2` parameters are of type `char*`. The `strcmp()` function expects arguments of type `char*` (actually `const char*`).

If you call `strcmp(*s1,*s2)`, that's an attempt to call `strcmp` with two arguments of type `char`. That won't give you incorrect results as you describe; it won't compile. At the very least, your compiler should be complaining about type mismatches.

If you don't have a `#include` for either `<string.h>` or `<cstring>`, the header that declares the `strcmp` function, then it's possible that the compiler won't recognize the mismatch -- but calling an undeclared function is invalid in C++.

It's true, as both of the other answers say, that you should be calling `strcmp(s1, s2)` rather than `strcmp(*s1, *s2)` -- but that doesn't explain the symptoms you're describing. Correcting the call to `strcmp()` will not by itself correct all the problems you're having.

I can think of a few possible explanations:

1. You're using an old compiler that doesn't complain about calls to undeclared functions. Get a newer compiler, or invoke your compiler with options that make it conform more closely to the language standard.
2. Your compiler is producing warnings (diagnostics don't have to be fatal) and you're ignoring them. Don't ignore warnings.
3. For some reason, you've decided to add your own declaration of the `strcmp()` function, perhaps something like `int strcmp(char s1, char s2);`. Don't do that. If you need a declaration for a standard function, add a `#include` directive for the appropriate header.

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest a (possibly) improved version of your function? This fixes the call to `strcmp`, removes the unneeded `result` variable, and adds const-correctness.

```
bool stringComparison::lessThan(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    return strcmp(s1, s2) < 0;
}
```

If `stringComparison` is a class I'd add another `const` to the end of the function definition.